# Alert role ignoring aria-label when using screen reader

Tags: reactjs, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am adding screen reader compatibility to a project (we are testing using NVDA). There are some sections of the app where we would like the user to be aware of any changes. I have added `role='alert'` to the element, which worked as expected (any change to the content resulted in the screen reader saying 'alert' followed by the new content of the element). However, we have now decided that instead of the alert being the exact content of the element, we want the alert to contain more context, so I added an `aria-label`.

It has clearly picked up on the `role='alert'` as it triggers when the element changes, but it treates the `aria-label` in an odd way. A code snippet is below - imagine, for the sake of simplicity, that the `typographyContent` variable changes to a new random string every 30 seconds. The `index` variable is so that we can uniquely identify each `Typography` element - there could be several on a page, and this is the context we wish to provide to the user.

```
const index = 1;
const typographyContent = 'I change based on some user input';
<Typography
    role="alert"
    aria-label={`Line ${index} now says: ${typographyContent}`}
    variant="body1"
    id={`line-${index}`}
>
    ${typographyContent}
</Typography>
```

Let's say that the text in the element with an `index` of 1 changes to be 'I am some new content'. I would expect the screen reader to announce: 'Alert: Line 1 now says: I am some new content'. What it actually does is announces 'Line 1 now says: I am some new content. Alert: I am some new content`.

Is there an easy way to get it to only announce the contents of the `aria-label` without also announcing the content of the element again, or do I need to accept the duplication of content?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you, tested in VoiceOver on Mac.

The key, I think, is adding `aria-relevant="text"`.

```html
<body>
<p
  aria-live="polite"
  aria-label="Line 2 now says: foobar"
  aria-atomic="true"
  aria-relevant="text">
  foobar
</p>

<script>
(() => {
  const liveRegionElement = window.document.querySelector('[aria-live]')
  setInterval(() => {
    const nextText = `${parseInt(Math.random() * 100)}`
    liveRegionElement.setAttribute('aria-label', `Line 2 now says: ${nextText}`)
    liveRegionElement.innerText = nextText
  }, 2000)
})()
</script>
```

Rather than using the alert role, you can use aria-live attribute. That way the content can retain its original semantic role.